# Pentaho Data Integration rounds off decimal values after 16 digits

Tags: rounding, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am trying to load a numeric value and I see that any number greater than 16 digits gets rounded off by PDI.

Whether I am using "Select values" step, or "Modified Javascript" or even "Generate rows" step - the value gets rounded off.

Like for example -

Input value - 346003617942512178

Output value - 346003617942512190

As you can see, the last 2 digits got rounded off.

Is there any setting in Pentaho, which needs to be changed so that this round off doesn't happen or atleast increase the 16 digit limit higher? I would like the data to load as is without any round offs but still being recognized as a Number and not a String.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: To solve this, You need to change InputValue column datatype from 'Number' to 'BigNumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look this transformation [BigNumber](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FL_fTT40ciTQhbBYwEBlyl-_UF_Q6yR_?usp=sharing), where input value is same but output is different based on data type.

Comment: Thanks.. I was not aware that BigNumber can handle any precision.